# Beginning SQL Spatial

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, spatial

I am busy trying to get my head around SQL Spatial data.

Is it possible for me to have a table with a column that stores the longitude and latitude of a point and then do a select statement to return all rows whose long/lat falls within X number of KM/Miles?

Is it possible to input that data from C# without any external programs?
Is Spacial fully supported in SQL Server 2008 Express?

Comment: Yes, yes, I don't know. Sorry, don't have time for a longer answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,2: [yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434647.aspx)
3: [yes](http://www.spatiallyadjusted.com/2007/11/20/microsoft-sql-server-2008-spatial-will-be-supported-on-free-express-versions/)

You might find Google quicker than SO for such obvious questions

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your questions directly is that
1) Yes it is possible to store that information and do those queries
2) Yes you can input data from C# without an external program
3) Spatial is fully supported in 2008 Express